# Understanding Recursive Algorithm And How It's Working

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I downloaded a free online course on Python Data Structures and Algorithms Question, so now I reached Recursion part of the course, the was a question which I had to solve recursively but I could not understand how to resolve it recursively can you please help me understand:

**QUESTION: Create a function which takes in a phrase and a set list_of_words.The function will then determine if it is possible to strip the string in a way which words can be made from the list of words. You can assume that the phrase will only contain words found in the dictionary,**

**My solution**

```
def word_split(s, arr_words):
    count=0
    answer= []

    for i in arr_words:
        if i in s:
            count += 1
            answer.append(i)


    print(answer)




s = 'ilovedogsJohn'
arr_words = ['i', 'am', 'a',  'dogs', 'lover', 'love', 'John']
print(word_split(s, arr_words))
```

**The course solution which I would love to understand how the recursive function is working**

```
def word_list(phrase, list_of_word, output=[]):

    for word in list_of_word:

        if phrase.startswith(word):
            output.append(word)

            return word_list(phrase[len(word):], list_of_word, output)
            #THIS IS WHERE I'M LOST HOW THIS RECURSIVE CALL IS WORKING

    return output



phrase = 'themanran'
list_of_word = ['the', 'ran', 'man']
output = []
print(word_list(phrase, list_of_word, output))
```

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Stack Overflow is not a tutorial service.  You neglected to provide a trace of the program operation *and* the *specific* point where you get lost.

Comment: The "course solution" will not always give the expected solution. For instance with phrase "theman", and list of words ["them","man","the"]. Secondly ,the challenge is to "determine if it is possible", so you would expect a boolean response (yes it is possible, or no it isn't). Maybe look for a different course...

Comment: ```return word_list(phrase[len(word):], list_of_word, output)```



 #THIS IS WHERE I'M LOST HOW THIS RECURSIVE CALL IS WORKING

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some comments about your solution:

- It is not a recursive solution, since the function is never called from within itself
- The function does not return anything. It prints a result, but the intention is to return it.
- The algorithm is not correct, as it just finds where in the string a word occurs, without checking that those matches do not overlap each other.

An example for the last point: `word_split("theman", ["them", "the", "man"]))` will output all words in the word list, while it should not output "them".

The "course solution" is not correct either:

- On the above input it will return ["them"], which obviously does not show how the whole string can be stripped with the available words. The correct solution would have to be ["the", "man"].
- It expects a third argument, which the function mutates *and* returns. This is an anti-pattern in Python. Either a function should return the result, but then not mutate its argument(s), or it should not return anything (`None`) and mutate an argument.

So I instead of explaining a wrong algorithm, I'll provide a correct one:

```
def word_list(phrase, list_of_word):
    if phrase == "":
        return []  # Yes, we stripped the whole string!
    for word in list_of_word:
        if phrase.startswith(word):
            output.append(word)
            result = word_list(phrase[len(word):], list_of_word)
            if result is not None:
                # Success, so prepend the current word
                return [word] + result
    # When we get here, we did not find a solution

print(word_list('theman', ['them', 'man', 'the']))
```

The idea with this recursive solution is this:

1. Find a word that can fit at the *start* of the phrase. Loop over all the available words to find such a word.
2. When you have such a word, we consider the phrase from which this word at the start is stripped. There are then two possibilities. Either the remaining part of the phrase can be stripped further to the end, or it cannot. This really is the same problem we started with, except that the phrase is shorter. So let's assume for a moment we have a correct algorithm, then we can just call it on the remainder of the phrase (of course, after chopping off the word we just found at the start).
3. The recursive call of step 2 can return a list with the words that cover exactly the remainder of the phrase. Or, ... it can return `None` when it is not possible. So if it is `None` we should not give up yet. Maybe we should have used a different word to start with. Like "them" and "the" both fit at the start of "theman". If we didn't get success with "them", we should still try with "the". If that recursive call indicates a success, we know we did the job. If it does not indicate success, we just need to continue from step 1 with the other words in the words list.
4. If the recursive call returns a list -- which indicates success -- then we know that with that list of words we can strip the remainder of the string. Now we can tell the caller that the whole string can be matched with one extra word (on top of the words we got from the recursive call).
5. If in step 1 there are no more words to match, and none of them led to success, we should give up: there is no solution. Return `None`.
6. Every recursive solution needs a "base case", otherwise you would have an infinite recursion. Here the base case occurs when the phrase is the empty string. Then we know that all words we matched -- while going deeper into recursion -- fitted the whole, inital phrase. We don't even have to match a word now, because... well... the phrase is empty. So we do return a list (to indicate success), but it is empty. The caller will prefix this empty list with one word, and return it to *its* caller, who will do the same, ... and so the list gets longer and longer until it arrives at the initial call.